# Haskell Data constructor not in scope

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've been researching it and wanted to try out some code with MVar. I'm checking this code through an online compiler.

Below is the code I'm trying to test:

```
main = do
  m <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ putMVar m 'X'
  r <- takeMVar m
  print r
```

And below here are the errors I'm getting:

```
main.hs:2:8: error: Variable not in scope: newEmptyMVar :: IO t1

main.hs:3:3: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: IO :: t0 -> IO a0

main.hs:3:8: error:
    • Variable not in scope: putMVar :: t1 -> Char -> t0
    • Perhaps you meant ‘putChar’ (imported from Prelude)

main.hs:4:8: error: Variable not in scope: takeMVar :: t1 -> IO a1
```

Comment: You need to `import Control.Concurrent.MVar`.

Comment: Are you sure the code and error message match? Most of the error makes sense, but I don't see why you'd get "Data constructor not in scope: IO :: t0 -> IO a0" from that code, since you don't mention IO.

Answer (score 2):

You must import a module that exports these functions; in this case, `Control.Concurrent` would be a good choice. If you didn't already know which module was needed, one way to find out is to use [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=takeMVar).